# How to merge two JSON arrays into a single merged array using Jolt in NiFi

Tags: java, json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a requirement in which I need to merge two JSON arrays into one. Currently the JSON is like this:

```json
[
  {
    "len": 1062,
    "count": 105,
    "info": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "count": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "count": "5"
      }
    ],
    "name": "s1"
  },
  {
    "len": 1062,
    "count": 105,
    "info": [
      {
        "name": "test3",
        "count": "8"
      },
      {
        "name": "test4",
        "count": "10"
      }
    ],
    "name": "s2"
  }
]
```

Now I need to merge the entire JSON array as a single array.

Like:

```json
{
  "len": 1062,
  "count": 105,
  "name": "s1",
  "info": [
    {
      "name": "test",
      "count": "4"
    },
    {
      "name": "test1",
      "count": "5"
    },
    {
      "name": "test3",
      "count": "8"
    },
    {
      "name": "test4",
      "count": "10"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am new to Jolt and hence don't know what to try

Comment: I have given a sample json content. The issue is more around merging of the json arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following **shift** and **cardinality** transformations :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&",
        "info": {
          "*": "&1[]" // &1 replicates the key "test" grabbing the literal's value 
            // after going up the tree one level
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only the single one from repeating components of the arrays which are generated from
    // the elements other than "info"
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": "ONE",
      "info": "MANY"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Great, one more thing, how can we also extract any other key:value say Id which is not part of the array but like:    "id": 123 which is above the test array

Comment: have updated the json to include the I'd attribute

Comment: This is yielding me I'd as an array, it should come as a field

Comment: No because if we give more indexes to the json , the I'd is retrieved as an array. I need the first I'd always and all the test objects as an array

Comment: Can you please share the exact JSON input for which you got such array issue.@codingprabhu

Comment: Input

[
  {
    "len": 1062,
    "count": 105,
    "info": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "count": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "count": "5"
      }
    ],
    "name": "s1"
  },
  {
    "len": 1062,
    "count": 105,
     "info": [
      {
        "name": "test3",
        "count": "8"
      },
      {
        "name": "test4",
        "count": "10"
      }
    ],
    "name": "s2"
  }
]

Comment: This is the exact input and output which is expected.

Comment: @codingprabhu OK, I've edited both the question and answer.

Comment: But still there is an error, we forgot the final start and end [] of the entire object like this: [{
  "len" : 1062,
  "count" : 105,
  "info" : [ {
        "name": "test",
        "count": "4"
      },
      {
        "name": "test1",
        "count": "5"
      },
      {
        "name": "test3",
        "count": "8"
      },
      {
        "name": "test4",
        "count": "10"
      }  ],
  "name" : "s1"
}]

Comment: Rest content wise it is quite good

Comment: Done and thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jackson and Lombok, you can deserialize the data and then reduce it.

You should be able to do something similar to Jackson with Jolt. The underlying reduce is the main business logic here.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

public class MergeData {
    public static final String DATA = "[{\"test\":[{\"count\":5,\"name\":\"highway\"}]},{\"test\":[{\"count\":6,\"name\":\"plateau\"}]}]";
    private static final ObjectMapper MAPPER = new ObjectMapper();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException {
        TestModel[] testModels = MAPPER.readValue(DATA, TestModel[].class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testModels));

        TestModel reduced = reduceTestModels(testModels);
        System.out.println(reduced);
    }

    private static TestModel reduceTestModels(TestModel[] testModels) {
        TestObject[] testObjects = Arrays.stream(testModels)
                .map(TestModel::getTest)
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .toArray(TestObject[]::new);

        return new TestModel(testObjects);
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class TestModel {
        private TestObject[] test;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{ \"test\": %s }", Arrays.toString(test));
        }
    }

    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private static class TestObject {
        private int count;
        private String name;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{ \"count\": %d, \"name\": \"%s\" }", count, name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```json
[
  { "test": [{ "count": 5, "name": "highway" }] },
  { "test": [{ "count": 6, "name": "plateau" }] }
]
```

```json
{ "test": [{ "count": 5, "name": "highway" }, { "count": 6, "name": "plateau" }] }
```

Comment: I know it via Java, here I am looking it specifically via jolt based on the usecase